# Redundancy needing definition

Tags: semantics

> He was the first who finished last.
>   He was the first who finished second.
>   ............................ third.

Is this kind of silly statement some kind of pleonasm? There's only one who takes up a certain place at the end of the race, so you *can* say he is the first who took it, which is also clearly redundant. Please let me know if this can be considered pleonasm (and which type of pleonasm if yes) or it's something else, or I should ask it somewhere else (English SE).

Comment: If one must delete references in a statement, leaving only a few quantifiers to deliver all the meaning, one should not be surprised to find all sorts of odd phenomena spilled on the floor. However, I wouldn't call this "pleonasm", which is a high faluting term for "wordy". This is, if anything, the opposite of pleonasm, since there are not nearly enough words used. And not nearly enough redundancy to pin down the multiple meanings engendered by deep deletions.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Jlawler is right;  there is nothing wordy about your three statements.   They are not redundant, and in fact need to have more words added to them to make them clear.

The statements not only make perfect sense but are compatible with one another if they refer to different sets of tasks, with each set consisting of more than one iteration of the same task.  Qualifying phrases would have to be *added* to clarify this.

(During the three races on Tuesday) he was the first to finish last. 
(During the three broad jumping contests on Wednesday) he was the first to finish second. 
(During the three pillow-making contests on Thursday) he was the first to finish third.